# jquery.sheet trigger formula calculation on cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am loading csv files from a server an inserting js function calls that create tables/sheets with jquery.sheet. Everything works thus far but when I put functions into the list they do not calculate.

The sheets (simplified)data object for the td has this before I modify anything:

```
Object {td: x.fn.x.init[1], dependencies: Array[0], formula: "", cellType: null, value: "=A2+B2+C2"…}
```

When I set the formula value it changes to:

```
Object {td: x.fn.x.init[1], dependencies: Array[0], formula: "=A2+B2+C2", cellType: null, value: "=A2+B2+C2"…}
```

So I understand how to set formula and value but what i wish to do is trigger an event to auto calculate a cell hopefully based on an "X,Y" co-ordinate, or find out if I am taking the wrong approach. 
I dont know if this helps but when I go to edit a cell it will appear as ==A2+B2+C2 not =A2+B2+C2

I would supply my code but because of the C# asp and js interaction it is not short I don't think it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Two things are essential to load a formula from a csv file to a jquery.sheet instance and then have it calculate. First is to manually set the objects ["formula"] property, while leaving off the '=' in the beginning because it adds its own. then you must trigger the "calc(s,true)" function with s as the sheets index and in my case I put true as the second parameter because I **believe** it forces calculations on cells with a function.

```
        var sheets = jQuery.sheet.instance[0];
        for (var s = 0 ; s < names.length; s++) {
            var sheet = sheets.spreadsheets[s];
            for (var k = 1; k < sheet.length; k++) {
                var row = sheet[k];
                for (var j = 1; j < row.length; j++) {
                    var col = row[j];
                    //alert(cell.value);
                    if (col.value.startsWith("=")) {
                        col["formula"] = col.value.substring(1, col.value.length);
                    }
                }
            }
            sheets.calc(s, true);
        }
```

If a better way is found please let me know. I do not think this is very scalable as it is O(n^3).

Comment: I will be selecting this as the answer in four hours.